# Is it possible to join the kubernetes worker node to kubernetes master without enabling ssh

Tags: kubernetes

I am installing kubernetes cluster on bare metal. One of the Prerequisites
An SSH key pair on your local linux machines. This ssh key pair is used to join the worker node with master.

Is it possible to join the kubernetes worker node to kubernetes master without enabling ssh?

Comment: Curious: what's your use-case?

Answer (score 0):

Well, SSH is required only, if you want to control all nodes from a single machine actually.
 I mean here operations like transferring all binaries/config files/certs required by minions.

If you want to setup Kubernetes cluster in really hard way, without SSH protocol part, you need to find a way ([alternative to SSH](https://superuser.com/questions/1032253/alternatives-to-ssh-to-connect-and-send-commands-to-a-server)) to be able to run on each worker node a similar command* to this (assuming the rest of [prerequisites](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/independent/install-kubeadm/#installing-kubeadm-kubelet-and-kubectl) are already in place):

`kubeadm join –discovery-token abcdef.1234567890abcdef 1.2.3.4:6443`

---

*I'm assuming you are bootsraping your cluster with [kubeadm](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/setup-tools/kubeadm/kubeadm/), if not please check [this](https://github.com/kelseyhightower/kubernetes-the-hard-way/blob/master/docs/09-bootstrapping-kubernetes-workers.md) tutorial.